# Setup a listener for listview to listen that is data changed?

Tags: android, listview

I have listviews in viewpages.I used asynctask for loading data from internet to my listview.When i load data in my fragment and set my adapter,my listview doesn't show the data.So i want to listen if data variable changed,so i can reset my adapter.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The adapter of your listviews should be notified about the change in data by using `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

You can even try `listView.invalidate()`

Comment: http://justpaste.it/l6b i had used this code in my fragment but it doesn't worked.